# How to make a list generated by md5deep in alphabetical order of relative paths?

Tags: shell-script, files, text-processing, sort, hashsum

If I want make a md5sum list recursively, then I would use `md5deep`, but it starts to pop up some problems such as it won't generate the md5sum file in alphabetical order. For example,

```
$ cd /media/sdcard/DCIM
$ md5deep -rl *
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e 2014-12-01/IMG_1969.png
c3a9d8cb047192a03b857023948a7ba6 2014-12-01/IMG_1971.png
bd12c358db0c97230b9d48f67b2c0c98 2014-12-01/IMG_1970.png
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just pass through `sort`:

```
$ md5deep -rl * | sort -k2
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e 2014-12-01/IMG_1969.png
bd12c358db0c97230b9d48f67b2c0c98 2014-12-01/IMG_1970.png
c3a9d8cb047192a03b857023948a7ba6 2014-12-01/IMG_1971.png
```

If your file name can contain newlines or other strangeness, use this instead (assumes GNU `sort`):

```
$ md5deep -0rl * | sort -zk2 | tr '\0' '\n'
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e 2014-12-01/IMG_1969.png
bd12c358db0c97230b9d48f67b2c0c98 2014-12-01/IMG_1970.png
c3a9d8cb047192a03b857023948a7ba6 2014-12-01/IMG_1971.png
```